# Google Analytics IP filters ignored

Tags: google-analytics

I have a personal site hosted on GitHub pages. I have google analytics set up with this code:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-<SOME_DIGITS>-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'anonymizeIp': false,
      'page': '/about/',
      'title': 'About'
    });
</script>
```

I've added IP filters to the analytics account for my WAN IP address and for my local IP addresses on my network in the admin settings of my google analytics account for the website property.

However, Google Analytics is still reporting traffic to both my live production site and my local development site which in skewing my stats badly for my low traffic site.

Comment: OK, I was able to partially rectify this for local traffic from 127.0.0.1 by adding a new exclusion filter for the "traffic to the hostname" filter. I'm still seeing traffic from my WAN IP though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think my analytics code is a bit dated. I threw in a `ga('set' 'anonymizeIp', 'false');` and that seems to have fixed things up.

Comment: You don't need to specify anonymityIp if it's false, just don't put the command.